# Acumatica. Rest API. Create Customer. Error

Tags: rest, api, acumatica

I'd like to create a Customer in acumatica using REST API. I imported into postman official JSON swagger config and I'm using following endpoint:

> http://*********/Acumatica2019DB/entity/Default/17.200.001/Customer

Method: PUT

Body:

```
{
  "CustomerID" : {"value" : "JOHNGOOD" } ,
  "CustomerName" : {"value" : "John Good" },
  "MainContact" : 
   {
      "Email" : {"value" : "demo@gmail.com" },
      "Address" : 
        {
          "AddressLine1" : {"value" : "4030 Lake Washington Blvd NE" },
          "AddressLine2" : {"value" : "Suite 100" },
          "City" : {"value" : "Kirkland" },
          "State" : {"value" : "WA" },
          "PostalCode" : {"value" : "98033" }
        }      
    }  
}
```

I'm facing following issue:

```
Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Subaccount: Error: Product Group, Department of Subaccount do not exist in the system. 
---> PX.Data.PXSetPropertyException: Error: Product Group, Department of SubCD do not exist in the system.
```

What do these values (Product Group, Department of Subaccount) mean? How can I configure them?

Comment: The best debugging method would be to navigate to the Customer screen in Acumatica website and try creating a customer with the exact same values. It should trigger the same error but can also likely highlight the problematic field. This appears to be some error tied to default value mechanisms.

Comment: Check the Default Customer Class if it is set correctly or not. The most part of the data for new customer records is copied form Default Customer Class.